# statement clarification of measure convergence.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I have a question on proving the following statements.

1. Given that $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of finite valued measurable functions defined on a set of finite measure $E$, and they converge pointwise to $f$ a.e. on $E$. Then, the $f_n$ converge in measure to $f$.
2. Given that  $\int \vert f_n - f \vert \rightarrow 0$ as $n$ tends to $\infty$. Then, $f_n$ converges in measure to $f$.

For (1), I can define $E_N=\{x \in E : \exists n>N \text{ s.t. } \vert f_n(x)-f(x) \geq \epsilon\}$ and show that this has measure zero as $N\to\infty$. The $E_N$ are decreasing and have finite measure, so by MCT for sets, the limit of the measures is equal to the measure of the intersection, which is $0$.

For (2), is it much more different, or not?

Comment: I would use Markov's (or Chebyshev's) inequality for (2): $\mu(\{|f_{n} - f| \geq \epsilon\}) \leq \epsilon^{-1} \int |f_{n} - f|$.

Comment: Oh ok and here the function we are applying the inequality to is defined as $f_n(x)-f(x)$?

Comment: Say we are applying it to $|f_{n} - f|$ for simplicity.

Comment: oh that's right thanks!